# How do I find errors in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I love jsfiddle and lately I've been learning javascript. There are of course many errors as I learn but I haven't figured out how to read error codes from console.

Latest I have is "1182:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Each section of my code is less than 1000 lines of code, but clearly combined it's more. Is there a way to use this info to find where the error is happening?

TIA!

Comment: JSFiddle is great for presenting demos and for quickly testing tiny things. If your project is that big: Build yourself a real, local development environment.

Comment: I should build in local development, but enjoy coming back to jsfiddle as a start place to build and see changes real time. I mostly build php pages, but building in jsfiddle in html, is helpful for me before I convert to php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The console should show you an underlined section where the line number is that you can click:

[image]

The line number does not correspond to the line number in the JSFiddle code editor, but it'll take you to the error location in the browser's Sources panel:

[image]

This problem is not specific to JSFiddle. Many online code editors without integrated consoles have this issue, and this solution should work in most of them.

Comment: maybe I need to switch online code editors. I don't see anything like this in chrome or edge browsers. But it looks like it works for you... what browser is this from?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 88, Windows 10. Firefox 85 has the same sort of clickable link that takes you to the JS source line that threw too. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeZRL.png

Comment: @Alex The console isn't part of the online code editor, [but of the browser itself](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).

Comment: @Ivar thanks, I just figured that out. But even in console, it references a line number greater than any in html, javascript, or css.

Comment: @Alex It's because the line numbers in the code editor's interface do not correspond to the line numbers in the HTML that gets generated as a result. Eg, in the screenshot above, you can see how the second line of the JS turns into line 112 of the generated HTML.

Comment: ahh, I get it now. So there is no easy way to troubleshoot. The console shows as if it would be a link in jsfiddle, but it's really a link in browser console. It would be nice if it did all this within jsfiddle, but I REALLY appreciate what you've shown as I can now find the errors.